# Access query to remove a group of records

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, subquery, where-clause

I'm trying to create a query in MS Access that only provides records where, when grouped if one of the criteria is TRUE, then that group is not included in the resultant data set.

I have the following fields ID, Teacher_Name, Dsp_Prd, Course_Key, Long_Description, Sec, Tot_Stds, Contains_CC, SchoolCode, IsCoTeach.

A teacher can appear multiple times in a given period (DSP_prd). However if they are assigned to a class as an assistant (IsCoTeach=TRUE) then all of the classes that they appear in should be filtered from the dataset.

For example:

[image]

The results should be:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from SchoolData as t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from SchoolData as t1 
    where t1.teacher_name = t.teacher_name and t1.dsp_prd = t.dsp_prd and t1.IsCoTeach = 'TRUE'
)
```

Comment: Sorry a little lost. "t" is a temporary table?  And for clarity mytable ="SchoolData"?  What is "select 1" in the subquery? And this is for MS Access? Sry I'm a noob.

Comment: @PvSyemya: `mytable` stands for the name of your table. Gordon Linoff edited my answer to make it explicit. `t` and `t1` are table aliases. `exists` just check if a row exists that satisfies the condition; we don't need the actual results here, so we use `select 1`.

Comment: Got it! Between the two of you (@GMB, @Gordon Linoff) I got it to work.  The only tweak I had to make was to convert TRUE and FALSE to -1 and 0. Thank you both!